# Grammatical name of a pattern involving sequence of nouns after an article

Tags: grammar-identification, article, definite-article

> **Das Brandenburger Tor** in Berlin markiert den Standort eines früheren Stadttores entlang der Berliner Stadtmauer in Richtung Brandenburg und wurde 1791 erstmals geöffnet. Als Symbol **des Kalten Krieges** markierte es während **der Teilung Deutschlands** die deutlich sichtbare Grenze zwischen Ost und Westberlin. Seit der Wiedervereinigung 1991 jedoch fungiert **das Brandenburger Tor** eher als Wahrzeichen der Hauptstadt

In the above text, what do we call these objects having a sequence of nouns following an article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all different. “Brandenburg” is a place name. Here it works somewhat like an adjective, but if these are formed with an “-er” ending they are still capitalised. (And if it didn’t end with -er it probably still would be as in the next case.)

The “kalt” is “Kalter Krieg” is an adjective, but “Kalter Krieg” is [capitalised as a fixed name](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Feste-Verbindungen).

In “die Teilung Deutschlands”, “Deutschlands” is a genitive. If it comes after the noun then it does not replace the article.

Comment: "fixed name" could you explain

Comment: @trystwithfreedom I have added a link.